# Launch Android emulator on Windows

Tags: android, windows, react-native

I'm trying to run the android emulator for my React Native project from Powershell. It seems I didn't install something correctly. From inside my React Native project I use `npm start` and the project runs, then I use `a` for Android and I get this: "**Error running adb: No Android device found. Please connect a device and follow the instructions here to enable USB debugging: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html#developer-device-options. If you are using Genymotion go to Settings -> ADB, select "Use custom Android SDK tools", and point it at your Android SDK directory.**"

I am not using Genymotion. I do not want to use USB debugging, I want to run an emulator on my desktop. Is this something that's possible?

### edit

From Powershell:

```
cd env:
ls path
C:\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\adb.exe
```

So it would seem `abd` is on my `path`.

Comment: what emulator you used to run react native?

Comment: @flix I am using android studio.

Comment: I'm not experience with AVD, but you should make sure `adb devices` showing at least 1 connected device, I'm using `Nox emulator` to run react native and I can connect `Nox` using `adb connect 127.0.0.1:62001`

Comment: Do I need to install `abd`? `adb : The term 'adb' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.`

Comment: it must existing in `/path-to-your-sdk/platform-tools` add  `adb` to your `environment variables path system`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows

Comment: @flix Please see my edit.

Comment: @MartinZeitler Please see my edit.

Comment: @smilebomb you need to add the paths (the SDK has two paths with binary executables), not the filename... as the variable name `%PATH%` might suggest.

Comment: the main Issue is your device (emulator) not connected with adb, i suggest to used your phone and check if `adb devices` detected your phone,

Comment: @MartinZeitler I've updated my environment variable to use `C:\AndroidSDK\platform-tools\` instead of the filename and restarted. The issue persists.

Comment: @smilebomb you might need to create an `AVD` android virtual device, so that the emu has an image to run... https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds (it obviously cannot find any device, while there is not even a virtual one)

Comment: @flix `adb devices` says no devices are attached. How can I resolve this?

Comment: makes sure `usb debugging` is enable, and the pop up will appear, just press `ok` then run `adb devices`, adb should detect your phone

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming from a Mac development environment, where pressing `i` after `npm start` automatically opens the Simulator app. This is not the same behavior on Windows. You first need to open Android Studio and launch an emulator, then the `a` command will work.

You can check if there's a device ready to run expo with `adb devices`. My list was empty until I started an emulator.